# How to run only failed test cases in QAF?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, qaf

We have close to 100 test scenarios based on QAF in feature files. I have a testng file which I invoke from command prompt through "mvn test" command.

Some tests fail occasionally, but when I run them again they pass. Is there some way where I can run only the failed test cases again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to run failed tests:

1. run failed test immediately it failed by setting `retry.count` property. Refer [list of properties](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/properties_list.html)
2. Run failed test after completion of entire execution by running generated failed test xml file under test results.